# Huge Array from config file or in .java

Tags: java, arrays, memory, config, lag

I have a quick question; What is more efficient? Storing huge arrays and other data in a config file or just in your java code?

My current project has a 200+ array in it and its code is triggered often, does it matter that theres a huge array in it?

Or is there another solution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to store large amounts of data in a database.

Having said this, a 200+ length array is not a very large array unless the size of the elements is particularly large.  Still, it seems a mouthful to write in the code—I might go with a config file or a database.

Another possibility is that the operations which are being performed on the array elements are time-consuming.  You may want to check that and possibly even post the operations on codereview.stackexchange.com, or post the code here with specific questions about its optimization.

Comment: I would go with a config file here. 200 items is not a lot of data. I find the easiest way of persisting data to a config file that is both human and machine readable is to use json and use Gson do read and write the file.

Comment: You may not want to use json and Gson - if the data is simple enough, you can just make the file tab delimited and that would be both human readable and machine readable with a simple Scanner.

Comment: That is certainly true. There are benefits to starting simple. And in my experience config files tend to get more complex over time. Having a single Config class that you serialize to json gives you a great deal of flexibility if you need to add additional configuration later without changing how you read the file. I am certainly not disagreeing with you.

Comment: It might be true that it's more time consuming to do it without a config file, but I have it done without one already anyways. Though, this relevant function is not the only one in my project, there's much more going on. I'm worried about the performance a bit more.

I would like to know which way uses the machine's memory and CPU more efficiently. Does it affect its performance if the array is being set every time the function is called? More than when reading from a file?

Comment: It will affect the performance if the array is constantly changing in size.  When arrays are changing in size, ALL the elements need to be reallocated into a new array because an Array is a fixed-size data structure.  If that is the case, you may want to use an ArrayList which buffers size changes, or a LinkedList which is a variable length data structure.  If you're just changing the values of some elements within the array, that doesn't affect performance much.

Comment: Not even that, my array and its values are always the same, it is inside a function that - when called - picks a random item from the list and continues with that item. - So can I state that when this function is called the array does not give any weight on the function? It only does so if values / length are changed within the function?

Comment: what does "the array does not give any weight on the function" mean?

Comment: does it make the function execute slower?

Comment: Nope.  Picking a random number between 0 and N and calling the relevant index of the array occurs in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

All large arrays are 200+, but not all 200+ arrays are large.

- if you use the array all the time, a config file seems the most feasible
- if you do not use it all the time, then a file, with initializing the array would be nice
- if you have to link a lot of data to the array elements and you already have a database, a new table would suffice